# How to select a dynamic value of an input field when a component is loaded in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

A dynamic value cannot be selected on the `AfterViewInit` hook. The value could possibly be selected later in angulars lifecycle; It actually works with the `AfterViewChecked` hook, but that would obligate me to set a flag so it only runs the first time. Which seems to be an over-complicated solution. I also get a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in production, which makes sense.

**What is a simple/proper way to select a dynamic value in an `input` upon loading a component without these lifecycle errors?**

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t9p69d) for a demo.

Here is some code where i used the `AfterViewChecked` hook.

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @ViewChild('myInput') public myInput;
  public value = 1;
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.myInput.nativeElement.focus();
    this.myInput.nativeElement.select();
  }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<mat-form-field class='amount' appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Convert</mat-label>
    <input #myInput matInput [(ngModel)]='value' />
</mat-form-field>
```

*Edit: I added in the `mat-form-field` code as it may be relevant.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create directive so we can access ngModel instance by Injecting NgControl. Then inside valueChanges we can set focus and select.

**Try this:**

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit,OnInit, ElementRef,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {take,} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private ngControl:NgControl) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription.add(this.ngControl.control!.valueChanges.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(v=>{
      console.log(v);
      this.elem.nativeElement.focus();  
      this.elem.nativeElement.select(); 
    }));  
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x77pcw)

Comment: I tried this approach earlier. It will work with a hardcoded value. But it won't select the value if it's dynamic: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x77pcw-kga1bn

Comment: Since you placing directive on input element you can get subscribe ngModel valuechagnes inside directive; something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x77pcw

Comment: That subscription approach is exactly what I was looking for. When you update your answer I will accept it :).